# how to "install" binaries?

Tags: binary

i tried building https://github.com/mhx/dwarfs as per instructions but it gives me errors at the end, so im guessing I can just download the binaries that should be dwarfs-0.7.0-RC5-Linux-x86_64.tar.xz but other than that i dont know what to do with the extracted folders, i need the utility to extract an archive. (on windows it was just easy installers and right click contextual menu)

i tried googling but im stumbling on conflicting informations on where to put it and this "PATH" variable, asd if anyone has some easy to understand tutorial video that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to extract the file just by double-clicking it in the File Manager. It will open in the default "Archives" application and you can extract it from there. From what I see, it will extract to its own subdirectory `dwarfs-0.7.0-RC5-Linux-x86_64`, which itself has three subdirectories: `bin`, `sbin` and `share`.

The common location for installing such third-party binaries in Linux is the `/usr/local` directory so I understand you have to copy the contents of mentioned subdirectories respectively to `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/local/share` (that part of course needs to be done as root).

You can do the whole above process in terminal, by issuing the following two commands:

```
tar -xJf dwarfs-0.7.0-RC5-Linux-x86_64.tar.xz
```

(this will extract the archive), and then

```
sudo cp -r dwarfs-0.7.0-RC5-Linux-x86_64/* /usr/local
```

to copy the contents of the extracted directory `dwarfs-0.7.0-RC5-Linux-x86_64`, as root (`sudo`) and preserving the directory structure (`-r`), to `/usr/local` directory.

Comment: thanks, much appreciated

Comment: Please accept the answer if it did solve your problem.